# Unable to install python3.6-venv on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, python-venv

I have `python3` inbuilt on my computer running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
I am unable to install `python3.6-venv`. It is showing the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3.6-venv is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3.6-venv' has no installation candidate
```

As suggested by some other SO posts, I also ran `apt-get update` but still the problem still persists. Please advise.

Comment: How about installing it using `pip`? As per: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation/

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get update` solved this issue for me